# Config variables not visible as environment variables in Heroku app

Tags: heroku, clojure, environment-variables, config

I've set a few custom config variables. I can see them in my application's settings->config variables. I can also see the values with the heroku config command. But when I start my application the environment variables are not there. I use (System/getenv "MY_VARIABLE_NAME") in Clojure to fetch them.

Is it because I try to retrieve them at boot time? Are they only available later? Or is there some twitch which I can get rid of by doing some trick? I've used config variables in Heroku before and they've worked, I don't know what's the problem here...

Comment: It might help to check the output of (System/getenv) to either the logs or a debug page, to see if anything else is coming through. The environment variables should definitely be present at boot time, they are not injected later.

Comment: None of the config vars come through via getenv. I've printed them all out and they're nil.

Comment: I'm more asking if any other heroku defined environment variables make it through by using System/getenv with no arguments so it lists everything including $USER and $PATH.

Comment: Good point! Just tested: user and path come through.

Comment: Any chance you could deploy a different application that reads the environment, it sounds more like your heroku environment variables are not being set than an issue with clojure. By submitting a different app you can verify it's not the applications fault, and is definitely a heroku / configuration issue.

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure that it's a heroku config issue specific to this app. I think I'll try that next, it's just a lot of work if I'll have to move everything to a new app and abandon the old one. I've got a development environment virtual machine, github mirror etc. And I'll be afraid this happens again there. One way to go forward would be just to hard-code the configs for the production version and abandon the public github repo...

Comment: I don't understand why any of the rest would need to change, can't you just delete a heroku app, and then make a new one and do an initial deploy? There should be no need to change anything else.

Comment: I think I understand the problem now: it turns out to be kind of Clojure-related after all. This code which I thought was running on startup is actually being evaluated in compile-phase. So it's probably macro-expansion which tries to read my variables which contain client id and secret for oauth2. I remember reading somewhere that at compile-time the config variables are not available in Heroku. That would also explain why PATH is available since it's always there in some form. This is third-party library integration code so I'll have to figure out how to defer the env var fetching.

Comment: @dgtized: Forgot to mention: I created another heroku app and the same problem manifested itself there with the same code.

Answer (score 1):

I was trying to retrieve client ID and secret for oauth authentication with Google from a config variable with System/getenv. I use a library called Friend to do this. Problem is, the set up for oauth parameters in that library is done via macros. And macro expansion happens compile-time. Heroku config variables are not available as environment variables during compilation (for good reasons). They are, however available via filesystem which was my solution to the problem. So instead of:

`(System/getenv "MY_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID")`

I'm using this:

`(slurp (str (System/getenv "ENV_DIR") "/" "MY_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID"))`

And it works!

Comment: It did not work for me. I got a message at Heroku with my S3 vars "-----> Running: boot build
          clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo: /AWS_ACCESS_KEY (No such file or directory)
           data: {:file "/tmp/boot.user1360068341951090917.clj", :line 17}
       java.io.FileNotFoundException: /AWS_ACCESS_KEY (No such file or directory)"